# How to create package-level functions?

Tags: function, kotlin

I was reading [the Kotlin Reference Guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html) and one part said:

> In Kotlin, unlike Java or C#, classes do not have static methods. In most cases, it’s recommended to simply use package-level functions instead.

How does one create a package-level function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[From the reference:](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html)

> All the contents (such as classes and functions) of the source file are contained by the package declared.

So simply by creating a source file like so:

```
package my.pkg

fun f0()=0
fun f1()=1
```

We can declare functions named `f0` and `f1` directly visible to the `my.pkg` package. These functions may then be imported and used similarly to classes:

```
import my.pkg.f0
import my.pkg.f1
```

Alternatively, using the `*` syntax:

```
import my.pkg.*
```

Comment: Really? From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html, I read:

Functions, properties and classes, objects and interfaces can be declared on the "top-level", i.e. directly inside a package:
...
If you do not specify any visibility modifier, public is used by default, which means that your declarations will be visible everywhere;

Comment: weirdly enough this thing is working for me only if I'm doing this in IntelliJ IDEA. If I'll run same code from kotlinc `kotlinc main.kt -include-runtime -d main.jar && java -jar main.jar` I'm getting **unresolved reference** error.

Comment: @IvanTemchenko I'm having the same issue. Any resolution?

Answer (score 8):

### Package-level functions

Package-level functions are also known as top-level functions. They are declared directly inside a file without creating any class for them. They are often utility functions independent of any class:

**UserUtils.kt**

```
package com.app.user

fun getAllUsers() { }

fun getProfileFor(userId: String) { }
```

Usage:

```
import com.app.user.getProfileFor

val userProfile = getProfileFor("34")
```

You don't need to manually write the `import` statement, just type the function name and the auto-import will do its job.

---

### Package-level functions with a class

When the functions are somewhat related to a class, define them just above the class, in the same file:

**User.kt**

```
package com.app.user   

fun getAllUsers() { }

fun getProfileFor(userId: String) { }

data class User(val id: String, val name: String)
```

Usage:

```
import com.app.user.getAllUsers

val userList = getAllUsers()
```

---

### `companion object`

When the functions are closely related to a class, define them inside a `companion object`:

**User.kt**

```
data class User(val id: String, val name: String) {

    companion object {

        fun getAll() { }

        fun profileFor(userId: String) { }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import com.app.user.User

val userProfile = User.profileFor("34")
```

---

That's it!