# How to get current local date and time in Kotlin

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin

How to get current Date (day month and year) and time (hour, minutes and seconds) all in local time in Kotlin?

I tried through `LocalDateTime.now()` but it is giving me an error saying `Call requires API Level 26 (curr min is 21)`.

How could I get time and date in Kotlin?

Comment: For API levels lower than 26 just add [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project, import `org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime` and then do as you tried: `LocalDateTime.now(yourTimeZone)` (I recommend specifying time zone, but if you don’t you’ll get the JVM time zone setting). See more in [this question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: check this link for your needed solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747490/android-get-date-before-7-days-one-week/57674721#57674721

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[`java.util.Calendar.getInstance()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()) represents the current time using the current locale and timezone.

You could also choose to import and use Joda-Time or one of the [forks for Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android).

Comment: an example would be nice.

Answer (score 105):

Try this      :

```
 val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
 val currentDate = sdf.format(Date())
 System.out.println(" C DATE is  "+currentDate)
```

Comment: Date is mostly deprecated and has been in the process of being phased out for years. I disagree with recommending it to a new learner.

Comment: New learner here. What's the replacement for `Date`?

Comment: @ClémentCardonnel just use the date you get from calendar.getInstance().

Answer (score 64):

My utils method for get current date time using `Calendar` when our minSdkVersion < 26.

```
fun Date.toString(format: String, locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()): String {
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(format, locale)
    return formatter.format(this)
}

fun getCurrentDateTime(): Date {
    return Calendar.getInstance().time
}
```

Using

```
import ...getCurrentDateTime
import ...toString
...
...
val date = getCurrentDateTime()
val dateInString = date.toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: this should be the accpted answer: easy and clean, I implemented it as a package level function (on package level functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778882/how-to-create-package-level-functions) to reach it from anywhere

Answer (score 23):

You can get current year, month, day etc  from a calendar instance

```
val c = Calendar.getInstance()

val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
```

If you need it as a LocalDateTime, simply create it by using the parameters you got above

```
val myLdt = LocalDateTime.of(year, month, day, ... )
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
val date = Calendar.getInstance().time
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance() //or use getDateInstance()
val formatedDate = formatter.format(date)
```

You can use your **own pattern** as well, e.g.

```
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd")
// 2020.02.02
```

To get local formatting use `getDateInstance()`, `getDateTimeInstance()`, or `getTimeInstance()`, or use new `SimpleDateFormat(String template, Locale locale)` with for example Locale.US for ASCII dates. 
The first three options require API level 29.

Answer (score 7):

To get the current Date in Kotlin do this:

```
val dateNow = Calendar.getInstance().time
```

Answer (score 7):

```
fun main(){
println(LocalDateTime.now().toString()) //2021-10-25T12:03:04.524
println(Calendar.getInstance().time) //Mon Oct 25 12:02:23 GST 2021
}
```

There are the above options, with the output added as comment.

Comment: ` return Loca¬lDateTime . now ().toString()` require Andorid O

Answer (score 6):

You can use this function

```
fun getCurrentDate():String{
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
return sdf.format(Date())
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
fun now(): String {
    return SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
}


    val currentYear = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy",Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val currentMonth = SimpleDateFormat("MM",Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val currentDay = SimpleDateFormat("dd",Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

checkout these easy to use Kotlin extensions for date format

```
fun String.getStringDate(initialFormat: String, requiredFormat: String, locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()): String {
    return this.toDate(initialFormat, locale).toString(requiredFormat, locale)
}

fun String.toDate(format: String, locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()): Date = SimpleDateFormat(format, locale).parse(this)

fun Date.toString(format: String, locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()): String {
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(format, locale)
    return formatter.format(this)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we got time in seconds we can do something like: (koltin language)

```
val dateObject = Date(timeInMillis)
val calendarInstance = Calendar.getInstance()
calendarInstance.time = dateObject
val hour = calendarInstance.get(Calendar.HOUR)
val minute = calendarInstance.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
val ampm = if(calendarInstance.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==0) "AM " else "PM "
val date = calendarInstance.get(Calendar.DATE)
val month = calendarInstance.get(Calendar.MONTH)
val year = calendarInstance.get(Calendar.YEAR)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple and easy

```
private fun getTime(): String =
        SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
```

set any desire format of date

Answer (score -5):

I use this to fetch data from API every 20 seconds

```
 private fun isFetchNeeded(savedAt: Long): Boolean {
        return savedAt + 20000 < System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

Another solution is changing the api level of your project in build.gradle and this will work.