# How to use Kotlin Javascripts "Date::toLocaleDateString" with "LocaleOptions"?

Tags: javascript, date, kotlin

I would like to code the Javascript line

```
date.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit' });
```

in Kotlin. I can not figure out how to set the second parameter for which only an interface type `LocaleOptions` exists. If I create an (anonymous) object then I have to initialize and use(!) all variables of interface `LocaleOptions` but I only want to use `hour` and `minute` without displaying the other components.

[See my 2nd comment for a possible answer to this question!]

Comment: Have you tried approaches listed on this SO page?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47006254/how-to-get-current-local-date-and-time-in-kotlin

Comment: No. The approach there is not related to the JS type `Date` but to the one inherited from Java. Might be possible to use it to circumvent the usage of `toLocaleTimeString`. But this does not answer my question.

Comment: Please put additional information in the question, not in comments. You can also answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper function `dateLocaleOptions` in date.kt can be used for this purpose:

`date.toLocaleTimeString(
  emptyArray(), 
  dateLocaleOptions { hour = "numeric"; minute = "2-digit" })`